# Powershell install software sequentially

Tags: powershell

please can you help me?
I made this script for silent software install on new formatted PC.
Why this will install Chrome only?
Which is the correct way to start msiexec.exe in powershell?
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
$7zip = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "7z*"
$vlc = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "vlc*"
$firefox = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "fire*"
$pdf24 = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "pdf24*"
$chrome = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "googlechrome*"

msiexec.exe /i "$zip" /L*V C:\MyLog.log /q ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
msiexec.exe /i "$vlc" /L*V C:\MyLog.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
msiexec.exe /i "$firefox" /L*V C:\MyLog.log /q ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
msiexec.exe /i "$pdf24" /L*V C:\MyLog.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
msiexec.exe /i "$chrome" /L*V C:\MyLog.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
.\AcroRdrDC1900820071_it_IT.exe /sAll /msi /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES
```

Comment: It should work like this. Please insert a line `Write-Host "Exit Code: $LastExitCode"` after each `msiexec` call so we can see what the error code of msiexec is. Also I suggest to use a different log file name for each call so they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: @zett42:  $lastexitcode is null. Empty line. It' doesn't write log.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` returns FileInfo or DirectoryInfo **objects**, not strings, so use `msiexec.exe /i $firefox.FullName` for instance instead of `msiexec.exe /i "$firefox"`. Then there's a typo. Your variable is `$7zip`, but you do `msiexec.exe /i "$zip"`. Are you sure the files you find are `.msi` files?

Comment: @theo $zip is $7zip. It's my copy error. I'll try with fullname, thanks for the lesson about objects. Now I understand.

Comment: @Theo FileInfo/DirectoryInfo convert to FullName when stringified like `"$fileInfo"` or `$fileInfo.ToString()`.

Comment: @zett42 Sure, but as you also know, too many people asking questions here have no idea about objects and simply treat all as if it were strings. That is why I always like to point out the difference.

Comment: @Theo Actually I prefer to be explicit and don't rely on `.ToString()`, which doesn't work consistently. Just wanted to point out that this is propably not the cause of the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem solved! After many attempts, I made it.

```
#remove space from filename
Get-ChildItem -Path . -file | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ' ', ''}
#getting filename of setup files
$7zip = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "7z*"
$vlc = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "vlc*"
$firefox = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "fire*"
$pdf24 = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "pdf24*"
$chrome = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "googlechrome*"
$adobe = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name "acro*"

#start msiexec to install files


Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $7zip /L*V C:\MyLog-7z.log /q ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow 

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $vlc /L*V C:\MyLog-vlc.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $firefox /L*V C:\MyLog-vlc.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $pdf24 /L*V C:\MyLog-pdf.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $chrome /L*V C:\MyLog-chrome.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow

Start-Process ".\$adobe" -ArgumentList "/sAll /msi /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. I wanna ask though, what kind of file is "$adobe" exe or msi?